# At what point does Jquery mouseenter() is better than CSS <>:hover?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

Currently creating some things and I was at a point of inserting a mouse animation. I first started of doing this by jQuery, but after a minute, I thought it'll be easiar doing it with CSS. In the end, it's just a hover animation.

At that point, I wondered: "I can do jQuery hover animations ( mouseenter(); mouseleave() ), as well with CSS:hover.. Where lies the difference in usage?"

And that's my question.

The only thing I can come up with is in a situation where the hover'ed over item should have a different state when the mouse has left than the original state. Such as a 'have seen' functionality.
i.e.

```
Regular: opacity:80;
:hover opacity:100;
mouseleave opacity:10.
```

Who can give an answer to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's relatively simple: use JS if you need to do actions which CSS cannot solve.

Such actions could be:

- AJAX
- Calculations
- Changing completely other elements in the DOM
- ...

This list can go on forever.

One exception to be noted is that you can use JS if you want to achieve browser compatiblity (if your specific CSS property is not supported across all browser(s) versions).

Answer (score 1):

While I'm voting to close as opinion based, I'd suggest that JavaScript is required when the hovered-item should effect a change in the sibling of an ancestor element, or a previous sibling to the hovered-over item.

If the use-case is to simply temporarily present the hovered-item differently, stick with CSS (it's easier, the browser can optimise); if the intent is to change or mutate other elements, then JavaScript (or one of its libraries) is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would recommend preferring the CSS solution whenever it's feasible, as the browser may well be able to optimize it. Only use the JavaScript/jQuery solution where the CSS one isn't feasible (because you need to do something you can't in CSS, because you need to support old browsers like IE7 that don't handle `:hover` correctly, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

`mouseover` and `mouseout` are DOM mouse events that can be handled by jQuery. jQuery also has method that can modify element's style - that is `jQuery.css()`. That's obvious.

Of course, CSS `:hover` is more efficient and more simple in your case.

Combination of mouse events and `jQuery.css()` are just a specific case of jQuery usage that evaluates to the same behaviour as CSS `:hover`. The same as a *square* is a specific case of a *rectangle*.

Comment: Also, in addition to it's simplicity, CSS is well-supported by the majority of web browsers and it's always (theoretycally) enabled. Javascript, on the other hand, can be disabled. So, in my opinion, he should use CSS as far as he can.

Comment: @AlejandroIván, well, there are exceptions in CSS support in major browsers (majority of CSS3) and in that exceptions jQuery should do the job. However I totally agree with you since you said _well-supported_ instead of _100% supported_.